# Study Loop quantum gravity

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, loop-quantum-gravity

I am a master's final year student in physics. In my curriculum I have courses on qft, qed and string theory but nothing on loop quantum gravity. I want to study the subject but I am not able to get any good books or online lectures on the subject. Please help.

Comment: What about [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGAwpoAbWke0mNt0sZH3IsuS2ThYxQcGZ)? There are notes in the description to the first video.

Comment: Here is the whole book: http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~rovelli/IntroductionLQG.pdf

Comment: A good resource on loop quantum gravity would mostly be a critical one, e.g. discussing how it doesn't recover classical geometry, doesn't reproduce axial anomaly, etc.